# Force TPL Tasks to run on a single core

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have ETL project which has a few processing component. The single component is producer-consumer based on BlockingCollection. All of the components are executed via Task.Run in parallel, wait for items to arrive from other components, process them and put the result to their output collections (think pipelines). All components are executed via Task.Run().

Is it possible to force tasks to run on a single core (I don't want them to take 100% of multi-core CPU) without setting processor affinity for the process (this seems like overkill)?

Please note that I still want tasks to run in parallel fashion - just on a single core.

Comment: processor affinity seems to be best bet. why you think it is overkill?

Comment: Affinity would be great if I can set it like use ANY core just a single one. But as far as I know (I might be wrong here) you need to explicitly specify a core - so if you have more processes like these you have to somehow "negotiate" between them which cores to use (if I have 8 cores available and two such processes I want them on different cores).

Comment: Do you care about which core your tasks execute on or do you care about that your tasks does not consume more CPU power than what a single core provides? [Is this an XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Also, you cannot execute anything in parallel on a single core although a single core can provide multitasking.

Comment: I don't care about which core is being used - I just want to limit a process CPU time to take max one core. And affinity "force" me to specify which core exactly I need - something I don't want to do this.

You are right re: single core/parallelism - what I meant that I want multitasking (thread context switching).

Comment: I think the answer to this is *No, it's not possible to force a process to run on a single core in the manner that you want it to*

Comment: @KarolKolenda I think you confuse core with thread. Or you confuse a resource restriction question (use at most 25% or 12.5% of CPU) for a task scheduling one (where and when to run tasks). Do you really care that all cores are used if CPU usage doesn't go above 25%,12.5% or whatever limit you want?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? The TPL already provides pipelines in the TPL Dataflow library. If you want to *throttle* tasks, use the TPL dataflow with a restricted DOP and input buffer. You could also create a pipeline of blocks, each of which uses only 1 task. You'd still get concurrent execution of each step. Or you can modify the DOP and buffer sizes of individual blocks to achieve the throttling, balance you want

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos All I want is the ability to run TPL tasks using multitasking/thread context switching (I don't care whether they'll be actually run parallelly) in such way that it will take the same amount of CPU like if they were running in a single thread.

I know that I can accomplish this via putting my solution to a separate process and set affinity to a single core but it would be nice if a) I wouldn't have to put it in a separate process, b) I wouldn't have to pin process to a specific core.

Comment: @KarolKolenda you keep describing the attempted solution, not the problem. If I wanted to parse 100K log files (which I do) but didn't want it to flood my CPU and RAM, I'd create an ActionBlock to parse file contents with say, a DOP of 2 (1 is the default) and set a small input buffer size (eg 5). Then I'd start posting file contents to the block. The DOP would limit how much CPU I could use and the input limit would prevent me from flooding RAM with unprocessed data

Comment: If I wanted to process log rows and store the results to a database, I'd use a TransformBlock or TransformManyBlock for parsing, and an ActionBlock to store the final results. A combination of DOP and input limits in each block would ensure I wouldn't flood either memory or CPU, but I'd still be able to read, process and output concurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Task Executes on a thread,the OS decides on which core it executes.

I don't think there is any other way other than settings Processor Affinity.

see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity.aspx

Are you sure that running them parallels on one core will benefit you with performance, why do you not want to allow the process to potentially use 100% cpu if it needs to? the os will still prioritize it with other processes and not necceserily allow this

You could also just lower the Thread/Process priority if what worries you is your process straining other OS processes:

Process Priority: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass.aspx
Thread Priority: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are probably right that I try to control it too much. The thing is that the system has two modules - a fast, high-availability one and slow, background ETL (I don't really care about its performance). I just don't want the second module to slow down in any way the first one. Limiting the number of cores seemed like a good idea to do this. But I agree that I can just let the OS decide (and lower process priority to Below Normal on a slow module).

That being said if that's the only way to do this, I will have to split these two modules (fast and slow one) into two dedicated processes.

Comment: I see, so maybe the solution is just to lower the thread/process priority of the ETL module. that way if the main one is running,and the ETL kicks in,the OS will still prefer it over the ETL one,since its priority is lower. i edited my main answer with links to these properties on MSDN

Comment: Given that the tasks are distributed to thread(s) via a scheduler - that can as well just use on thread. Wrong answer.

Comment: While a custom TaskScheduler is a nice solution,it will force all tasks to run on a single thread,which will result on running on one core,but no tasks will run in parallel(although multiple threads on one core != real parallelism) - if we limit everything only to one thread, all the usage of tasks and TPL here are pointless. we can just have one thread processing the collection and that's it. In his question - Karol wanted to be able to run the Tasks in Parallel on his ETL process - to not slow down the main process, I don't think using one thread is the smart solution here.

Comment: Actually it will - if you are ignorant enough to replace the default task scheduler. If you do not do that and run your tasks on another task scheduler - then it will not. Interesting how understanding the documentation makes things possible? http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/specialized-task-schedulers-in-net-4-par/228800428 has some code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is entirely possible. You just need to implement your own [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx).

In fact, the example in the TaskSchduler's API docs illustrates how to accomplish exactly what you want--they implement a `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` that lets you set the number of worker threads that you want to use.

The links in the Remarks section of the API docs are are also valuable. The [Samples for Parallel Programming with the .NET Framework 4](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples) project contains a slew of alternative thread schedulers, described in detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx). They may inspire you to think of alternative approaches to scheduling these tasks.

The only twist here is that you can't use the `Task.Run()` shortcut anymore--you'll need to go through a TaskFactory [instead](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Comment: but wont this cause the tasks to not run in parallel at all? if we have only 1 thread we are guaranteed to one core,but also no parallel processing of tasks

Comment: @yonigozman That's a terrific question! I thought about diving into this in my answer but was worried that I'd derail the discussion. The problem here is that everyone's being too loose with the term "parallel"--I think Karol's after concurrency, not parallelism. For background, the best discussion I've heard so far about parallelism vs. concurrency is Rob Pike's famous talk [here](http://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism) (it's about Go, but very relevant and I heartily recommend it to any developer). In his lexicon, you're never running in "parallel" on one core.

Comment: ...so now that we've framed the discussion in Pike's terms, I think this question is really about concurrency, not parallelism: how can Karol have one core *deal* with 2+ things at once since one core cannot *do* 2+ things at once (using multiple threads is an option, but on one core you'll just incur context switching overhead). So that brings us to my suggestion: just use a single thread and execute your tasks as fast as you can. And with Tasks you still get "concurrent" execution (*dealing* w/ 2+ things)... (So a lot of this is my own interpretation.. your's and Karol's may vary from mine!)

Comment: @yonigozman is right - this guarantees a single thread/core but then one task needs to be finished before another one can start - and I do not want such behavior.

Comment: Ok, so you need a bunch of threads that'll frequently preempt each other. That's fine, but it deserves further insight into your requirement. (For example, what should be the basis for one thread preempting another on that one core? IO completion?)

Answer (score -1):

When using `Task.Run()`, you have a very low control over job and everything is parallel, except if you use a custom Scheduler.

Rather than this technical solution, I suggest using [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl), that could be viewed as a higher layer of handling threaded jobs.

In TPL, you can choose blocks types to process your data, and even connect blocks between them, so when an item has just finished processing, the result can be enqueued in next TPL Block.

**You can use an `ActionBlock<T>`** : you define the code to execute for each item to be processed, and when data is available for ActionBlock with `.Post()`, it is automatically processed... in parallel. But for your need, you can specify `MaxDegreeOfParallelism=1`.

So with this method you cannot control the Core on which you execute your code, but you ensure all items will be processed sequentially and won't use more than one core at the time.

[image: ActionBlock]

```
var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(
      // Simulate work by suspending the current thread.
      millisecondsTimeout => Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout),
      // Specify a maximum degree of parallelism.
      new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
      {
         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
      });
// Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-3.1
```

You can also read this [complete article about TPL](https://livebook.manning.com/book/concurrency-in-dot-net/chapter-12/), very interesting.

Comment: Can downvoters explain the reason ? my solution ensures all will be executed at maximum on 1 core at the time. I recall you the original question : "I don't want them to take 100% of multi-core CPU".  Thanks.